# Line-break after 3 images with css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have six icons on my website. I want three of them to be on one line and the others on the second **only when the media screen is 400px**.
So I should do it with `@media screen and (max-width: 400px)`. But my main problem is that I dont know how to make the line break with 3 icons in the first line and the next three in the second line.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
#line-break {}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div id="line-break" class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
```

***FIDDLE:*** https://jsfiddle.net/ayf8u5s9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a `<br>` tag after the third icon and hide it when the viewport is wider than 400px with this [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries): `@media screen and (min-width: 400px)`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ayf8u5s9/3/) :

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: All comments was helpful, but in the end I take your method so I accept your answer. I gave you all +1 because I really read everything, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `display: inline-block`, use `float` to line the `div`s up. Then on media query, clear the `float` on the `line-break` one.

```
.icon {
  float: left
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #line-break {
      clear: left;
    }   
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ayf8u5s9/2/

Snippet:

```css
.icon {
    float: left
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    #line-break {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div id="line-break" class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` and `clear` within your

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px)
```

`@media` query:

```css
    .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    }
    
    .icon:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="line-break" class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to put each 3 icon in one div then make these divs `display: inline-block` then when the media screen is 400px make it `display: block`

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.col1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media(max-width: 400px) {
  .col1 {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col1">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col1">
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Home.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all icons div in one main div and then in 400px media screen add class width which takes only 3 icons ,it automatically send the three others on the next line

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon { width:auto; float:left }
.icon:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: both; }
```

Modify the styles as above. This will break to next line after every 3